# Is this sentence correct using the right choice of words?

Tags: sentence

Does the way I wrote the following sentence make sense?

> The story begins with Olaf speaking about his experiences and
>   perception of life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does make sense, but you could also say:

> The story begins with Olaf relating his experiences and
>   perceptions of life.

Answer (score 0):

"Cool story, Hansel!"

Yes, it makes sense. Although I might change it to say: "experiences and perceptions of life." (That way experiences and perceptions are both plural.)